What could justify a fantastic amphibian?
The fantastic amphibian is a 2-metre-long generic herptile which has both lungs and gills. Curiously, it can breathe underwater indefinitely without ever surfacing for air, yet can also survive indefinetely on land with as low as 50% humidity with little more water than a terrestrial animal needs to drink. It retains these abilities year-round and retains them throughout its life once it reaches maturity
What environment could make these abilities significantly more useful than just breathing air or just breathing water?

Intermittent Rivers
Some rivers are not rivers year-round.  They dry up during the dry season, and sometimes stay dried up for many years at a time.  Many amphibians (mostly toads) adapted to this sort of climate have to burrow under the dried up river and hibernate during the dry season, but for a differently evolved amphibian, it might be more advantageous to leave the dry river bank and travel the land looking for remaining watering holes and food.
The main reason amphibians don't already do this is because of predation.  An amphibian on the surface rarely has all of the same adaptations for the surface as the things that eat them, but if this environment lacks natural predators for a given amphibian, it could be more selectively fit to stay mobile during a dry spell to seek out better habitats than always hide and wait for the next rains to come.

In China there is the giant salamander which more or less fit the bill, so there is really nothing fantastic about your reptile:

The South China giant salamander (Andrias sligoi) is a species of very large salamander endemic to southern China, mainly in the Pearl River basin south of the Nanling Mountains. It may be the largest species of salamander and the largest amphibian in the world.
It is possible that A. sligoi may be the largest extant amphibian today, a superlative generally attributed to A. davidianus. The largest known Andrias specimen was a 1.8 m (5.9 ft) individual captured near Guiyang in Guizhou Province in the early 1920s.

Being able to dwell in both environments is an advantage in itself when they overlap often, like in humid environments.

Can giant salamanders actually survive on land? Everything I've been reading says they're fully aquatic
